# Which malts have the highest SMM (precurser of DMS) content?

Tags: all-grain, off-flavor, dms, pilsner

I've been scouring the internet, trying to find some kind of list of the SMM content in various malts so I know when it would be wise to do a 90 minute boil. I can't find anything, just the definition of the off-flavor.

I know Pilsner malts are high, but that's it!

Any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20812384), the use of nitrogen fertiliser can increase SMM levels in (malting) barley across the board.

[This guy](http://www.winning-homebrew.com/dms.html) seems to have the right answer though:

> When using all pilsener malt or pale
>   malt, it may be advisable to boil your
>   wort for at least 90 minutes to reduce
>   the Dimethyl Sulfide levels.

He also notes that the DMS flavour is more detectable in the lighter styles of beer:

> Lighter beers with
>   high adjunct ratios or low gravity
>   beers will allow the off flavor and
>   odor to be more detectable, while dark
>   German beers, all-malt beers and any
>   other flavorful beer will hide the
>   canned corn notes.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the lighter the malt the more SMM it will have.

Answer (score 0):

6-row pale malts have higher concentrations of SMM than 2-row pale malts.

Comment: These days, the diastatic power of 2 row and 6 row malts is nearly the same.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the downvote Denny.  Okay, I edited the part about diastatic power out.  My answer to the question at hand here stands.

Comment: I didn't do the downvote.  Poor assumption.

Comment: Ah, my apologies then.