# What exactly does all-malt mean?

Tags: all-grain, reinheitsgebot

My understanding is that all-malt simply means no adjuncts (sugar, corn, rice, ect) in your beer.  They also say that all-malt beers are prone to DMS.  They also say that dark german beers are essentially immune to DMS.  Technically, aren't all german beers all-malt, due to Reinheitsgebot?

Am I missing something?

Comment: You must have had a really stinky batch to have all these DMS questions!  I've been there though, it's definitely worth talking about.

Comment: Haha actually no, I haven't had any of these issues yet, I just do way too much research for my own good and get curious about things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of all-malt is right, but it's incorrect to say that an all-malt beer is prone to DMS. DMS presence depends on the base grain used (as you asked in your [previous question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4019/which-malts-have-the-highest-smm-precurser-of-dms-content)) and how the beer was brewed -- longer boils remove DMS from your beer.

Unlike pilsners, dark lagers use a higher proportion of darker grains (Munich, Vienna, etc.) in the grist. These darker malts have a lower SMM content, so less DMS is created. But these beers still have a high proportion of plisner malt, so they would be boiled for 90 minutes (or more), driving off the DMS.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that contributes to DMS issues in the beer is poor brewing practices.  The ingredients are not to blame; malt or otherwise.